# Configuration error при запуске Jest

Tags: javascript, angular2, юнит-тесты, typescript, jest

Моя эпопея с Jest продолжается, нужен совет знающего. В чем суть - вся `js` часть проекта имеет следующий путь относительно `package.json` => `app/assets/javascript/`, тест и тестируемый компонент лежат тут => `app/assets/javascript/app/pricing/`, в тестируемый `pricing.component` импортируется `pricing.service` из этой же директории, а в сервис импортируется `api.service` с адресом `app/assets/javascript/app/shared/` и вот на него то `Jest` и ругается, точнее он ругается на сам путь в импорте `import { ApiService, QueryFn } from 'app/shared';`.
 При этом, если убрать `api.service` из импортов, то тесты запускаются без проблем. Сам `Jest` в терминале пишет какие то не совсем понятные пути с этому сервису, а предложенные решения в интернете не слишком помогли.

Собственно ошибка:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**pricing.component**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { PricingService } from './pricing.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-pricing',
  templateUrl: './pricing.tpl.pug',
  providers: [PricingService]
})
export class PricingComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private pricingService: PricingService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.pricingService.load().subscribe(i => console.warn(i))
  }
}
```

**pricing.service**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

import { ApiService, QueryFn } from 'app/shared';

@Injectable()
export class PricingService {
  private query: QueryFn;

  constructor(private api: ApiService) {
    this.query = this.api.query(`/api/v2/currencies`);
  }

  load(): Observable<any> {
    return this.query();
  }
}
```

**pricing.spec**

```
import { TestBed, ComponentFixture, async } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { PricingComponent } from './pricing.component';
import { PricingService } from './pricing.service';

describe('PricingComponent', () => {
  let component: PricingComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<PricingComponent>;
  let service: PricingService;
  const serviceStub = {
    load: () => {}
  };

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [PricingComponent],
      providers: [{
        provide: PricingService,
        useValue: serviceStub,
      }]
    }).compileComponents()
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
      fixture = TestBed.createComponent(PricingComponent);
      component = fixture.componentInstance;
      fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create the comp', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

**package.json в части jest**

```
"jest": {
    "preset": "jest-preset-angular",
    "setupTestFrameworkScriptFile": "./setupJest.ts",
    "verbose": true,
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "ts",
      "tsx",
      "js",
      "jsx",
      "json",
      "node"
    ],
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.jsx$": "babel-jest",
      "^.+\\.js$": "babel-jest",
      "^.+\\.(ts)$": "./node_modules/jest-preset-angular/preprocessor.js",
      "\\.(pug)$": "pug-jest"
    },
    "testMatch": ["**/__tests__/**/*.+(ts|js)?(x)" , "**/+(*.)+(spec|test).+(ts|js)?(x)"],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "/^app\/(.*)/": "<rootDir>/app/assets/javascript/app/$2"
    },
    "testPathIgnorePatterns": [
      "config",
      "app/shared"
    ]
  },
```

Собственно вот в чем вопрос - как настроить конфиг `jest` так, чтобы он адекватно воспринимал такие импорты `import { ApiService, QueryFn } from 'app/shared';`?

Answer (score 0):

У меня наконец появилось время вернуться к тестам и вот что я выяснил - внутри пакета `jest-preset-angular` есть файл `jest`-конфига под названием `jest-preset.json` и внутри него есть такие строчки:

```
"moduleNameMapper": {
    "^src/(.*)": "<rootDir>/src/$1",
    "^app/(.*)": "<rootDir>/src/app/$1",
    "^assets/(.*)": "<rootDir>/src/assets/$1",
    "^environments/(.*)": "<rootDir>/src/environments/$1"
  },
```

Это подходить далеко не для всех проектов, поэтому внутри своего `package.json` в конфигурации  `jest` нужно задать `"moduleNameMapper": null,` а затем добавить:

```
"moduleDirectories": [
    ".",
    "root/path",
    "root/path/to/your/lib",
    "node_modules"
],
```

На этом вы сможете использовать не только библиотеки из `node_modules`, но и свои собственные.